# Soft delete after 24 hours with Django

Tags: python, django, celery, django-orm

I need store a row in DB and after 24 hours mark it as deleted, (just with a flag variable), I am not clear about how I will get this done.

I've thought to use [Celery+Django](http://docs.celeryproject.org/en/latest/django/first-steps-with-django.html) to run async task, but when should it be ran? every row will have to be marked as deleted in different moments.

Is there any Django function to achieve this?

Edit:

Every row has a User related, I need notify the related User when his row has been marked as deleted.

Comment: Have you had a look at periodic tasks in celery? http://celery.readthedocs.org/en/latest/userguide/periodic-tasks.html

Comment: @Railslide Thanks, yes I had, but I think run a task making queries to DB is too hard, I'd use it as a last resort.

Answer (score 3):

Don't store the flag or the expiration date. Only store when the record was added. From that, calculate when it should be considered expired. You can leave that to the database by adding a calculated field, or do it in the Django model. Either way, don't store anything that can be calculated from more general data.

Regarding notifications, the heavyweight method is what @PabTorre described; schedule a task already when the record is created. Otherwise just schedule the notification task to run often enough (every so many minutes). Based on the last time the task was run, you can infer whether for any particular expiration a notification has already been sent.

Comment: yeah, you could build a view filtering where "created_time + 24 hours < now()" and that'll get the trick done... or a materialized view that can be refreshed at regular intervals (e.g. if you want them to expire on the hour mark not exactly at the time of expiration)

Comment: Agree with this solution, but would add a couple things: 1) check out celerybeat, which is part of django-celery iirc. It's great for running the periodic task of checking the view or otherwise running queries for the records that need to be soft deleted. 2) be careful with scheduling individual tasks to run in the future. I've heard that the tasks can clog up your celery workers, which will basically pull such messages from the queue and then sit on them in until it's time to execute the task.

Answer (score 1):

One approach that could work, since you're doing a soft delete. 
Add a column for "expiration date", when you create a record, you add a timestamp of now + 24 hours. 
From there you could take several paths. 
Build a view that filters the table to see only the records where "expiration date" > now()... or that sets a binary flag on that same check. 
Then query that view.

Comment: I think this will work every time someone access that view. I was thinking more about something like a listener expecting for a row expires.

Comment: hmm... well. You can calculate the time when the record must expire and use that information to run the cron job.